# Removing dotfill from table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I've been searching for hours and haven't been able to find a solution, it's beginning to drive me a bit insane! I need to add some lines to the end of my table of contents for files associated with my thesis. These lines shouldn't have page numbers as there are no pages associated with them. After a lot of Googling, I was able to get the page numbers to disappear, but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get the dotfill to disappear too.

I am using a specific document class maintained by my university for compliant thesis formatting.

Here is the code I've added after my `\makebibliography`:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Supplementary Files Available Online}{}{}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{First Data Table}{}{}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Second Data Table}{}{}}
```

It's perfect except for the dotfill!

[image: how the code looks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not told us what class you are using or how you have eliminated the page numbers, so I have no idea what you have done. In general if you ask a question then provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.

The general means of changing the look of the ToC is the `tocloft` package.

I have tried to invent an MWE for your problem but, as you said,  it started to "drive me a bit insane". Eventually I came up with this but I have no idea whether it addresses your actual problem although it does give ToC entries that you say you want. Note that I am a GOM (Grumpy Old Man).

```
% atocprob.tex  SE 635685
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{center}
Lots of probably irrevelant stuff.
\end{center}

\chapter*{REFERENCES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}

%%%%% bibliography

\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{50000}

%\end{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Supplementary Files Available Online}{}{}}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{First Data Table}{}}%{}}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Second Data Table}{}}%{}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hspace{1.5em} First Data Table\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hspace{1.5em} Second Data Table\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the document class is specific to my university so it's not the most helpful (ucetd). Your solution definitely worked though! Unfortunately, using the tocloft changed the formatting of the entire TOC and I'm worried it won't pass the criteria from my dissertation office. I played around some more after trying that and found I can hack it a bit by just adding a bunch of \hspace{} at the end of the titles, leaving no room for the dotfill. Thanks for the help!